# Нет нужных файлов в pyqt5-tools

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Установил PyQt5 и pyqt5-tools на свой компьютер. Хотел открыть QtDesigner, но обнаружил, что в папке pyqt5-tools нет некоторых файлов и папки Qt. Переустанавливал по нескольку раз библиотеку, сам Питон, но всё как обычно. Файлы, которые есть в папке библиотеки можно увидеть на скриншоте. На остальных компьютерах всё работало.[image: Файлы в папке pyqt5-tools]

Comment: т.е. вы в CMD/консоли/терминале набираете `designer.exe` нажимаете Enter и что?

Answer (score 0):

Новая версия PyQt5-tools разбита на 3 части. QT designer находится в папке Python3N\Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin, где Python3N - Ваша версия python. Полное описание смотрите на странице https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/